# とは言わない　ｖｓ　とは言えない？違いは？ To wa Iwanai vs To wa Ienai differences?

Tags: meaning, nuances

In the sense of "I don't want to say ___" or "can't say". E.g. 悪い事いわない.

Can you use 言えない instead? Any difference in subtlety? Or is this strictly only for really being unable to physically say something (e.g. mouth gagged) as compared to being unable to comment on something one is uncertain about?

Comment: "Want" has nothing to do with either of those forms...

Comment: To contrast the two: この映画はつまらないと言わないけど、面白いとは言えない。- "I **won't** say it's a boring movie, though **can't** say it's an interesting one."

Comment: ^ `つまらないと言わないけど、～～` <-- you need a は there. 「この映画はつまらないと**は**言わないけど、面白いと**も**言えない。」とか・・

Comment: ^ Thanks for correction!  I also see now that I put "though" in the wrong place in the translation...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, 言えない is just "(someone) cannot say something", and 言わない is just "(someone) doesn't/won't say it". The reason for 言えない can be anything; it can be physical, mechanical, mental or social.

Specifically, [悪いことは言わない](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%82%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) is an idiomatic set phrase you need to remember. This 言わない is not interchangeable with 言えない.

悪いことは言えない is of course grammatical, too, but it's not an idiomatic expression at all. It just means "I cannot speak ill of (someone/something)." For example, if you're a professional athlete sponsored by a company, you may want to say スポンサーについて悪いことは言えない. This is an example of 言えない for a social reason.